# My YouTube app is stuck and never starts downloading on iPhone 6, iOS 10 (screenshot attached)

Tags: ios-appstore, iphone, ios, youtube

[image]

I have waited for an hour it doesn't work. All others apps are downloading smoothly. Also restrictions are off. I also tried to download it through iTunes from my laptop.

Comment: That "Get" button is for the Google app below, not the Youtube app, which shows the non-responsive download circle.

Comment: @Umer Aslam - have you forced a restart of the device by holding down the Home & Power buttons?

Comment: @tetsujin I am talking about the youtube app. The download circle is not responding. I have restarted the phone many times. But the circle remains just there.

Comment: @IconDaemon No I haven't. What does the force restart do??